Storage spaces operational status "IOError, OK"
I have a Storage Pool of four NVMe drives. One of them shows strange status:
Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "ADATA*"

Number FriendlyName     SerialNumber                             MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage
------ ------------     ------------                             --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----
2      ADATA LEGEND 750 0000_0000_0000_0000_707C_1823_2002_4000. SSD       False   {IO Error, OK}    Warning      Au...
5      ADATA LEGEND 750 0000_0000_0000_0000_707C_1823_2922_0000. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Au...
4      ADATA LEGEND 750 0000_0000_0000_0000_707C_1823_2022_0000. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Au...
3      ADATA LEGEND 750 0000_0000_0000_0000_707C_1823_2022_0000. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Au...

As a result, the virtual disk shows Degraded
According to Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-states):
There was a temporary error accessing the drive.
Action:

If the drive doesn't transition back to the OK state, you can try using the Reset-PhysicalDisk cmdlet to wipe the drive.
Use Repair-VirtualDisk to restore the resiliency of affected virtual disks.
If this keeps happening, replace the drive.

But that's unclear to me, does that mean disk "transitioned back" to OK state, or what actions should I do in that case?

The best course of action depends on the urgency of your data and your comfort level with troubleshooting. Here's a breakdown of two approaches:
Priority: Minimize Downtime and Data Loss (Conservative Approach):

Monitor the Drive:  First, observe the drive for a short period (e.g., 15-30 minutes). If the status changes to just "OK" during this time,  you can likely assume it was a temporary glitch and no further action is needed.
Prepare for Repair: If the status remains "IO Error, OK",  back up your critical data  stored on the virtual disk associated with the Storage Pool. This ensures you have a copy in case the situation worsens.
Seek Professional Help (Optional):  If you're uncomfortable using PowerShell cmdlets like Reset-PhysicalDisk or Repair-VirtualDisk, consider seeking assistance from a technician or someone familiar with managing Storage Spaces.

Priority: Troubleshoot Yourself (Aggressive Approach):
Before proceeding, ensure you have a recent and complete backup of your data.

Try Resetting the Drive (Risky):  Use the Reset-PhysicalDisk cmdlet to potentially fix the drive. This might erase data on the drive, so only proceed if you're comfortable with the risk and have a backup.
Repair Virtual Disk (if necessary):  After resetting the drive (or if replacement is needed), use the Repair-VirtualDisk cmdlet to restore the resiliency of the virtual disk, assuming the data is still intact.
Monitor Closely:  Keep a close eye on the drive's status after resetting. If the error recurs, consider replacing the drive.

Important Note:

Whichever approach you choose, monitor the health of the drive and the virtual disk status after taking any action.
If the errors persist, replacing the faulty drive might be necessary.

Additional Tips:

Consider scheduling regular backups of your data to prevent significant loss in case of drive failure.
Research the specific Reset-PhysicalDisk and Repair-VirtualDisk cmdlets to understand their usage and potential risks before using them.

Ultimately, the best approach depends on your individual circumstances and risk tolerance.

Hi, I appreciate a lot your detailed response. The IOError/OK state was up for several hours, so I decided to reboot the system during inactivity period. After reboot, the OperationalStatus is now just OK without IOError, and HealthStatus is Healthy. This ok status is now there for a day, so it seems like problem solved and something glitched, however will take a close eye on this drive now. I'll accept your response as answer

You might have the same issue popping up again and again! Unless you fix the root case of it, of course...

You can just ignore this status, it should disappear after reboot. If it won't do that you can schedule a downtime window, remove the disk from the pool, eject it, wipe it off with DiskPart or whatever and add to the pool again kicking "rebuild". If the disk is healthy it will be accepted again and you won't have any issues after that. If the disk isn't healthy, it should start throwing errors on the adding to the pool attempts. In this case it's good idea to have a spare one nearby. Good luck!
